# React Native press and hold, drag finger to another touchable and capture touch by that view

Tags: ios, react-native, touch, gesture

In my React Native app I'm trying to have a button that the user can long press, and *without lifting their finger*, able to interact with another view. Here is roughly what I want:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Think of it like how 3D touch/long press worked prior to iOS 13/14 (depending on place in system and device): user either 3D touched or long pressed a button, for example an app icon, and a contextual menu popped up. Then, users could, *without lifting the finger*, hover onto one of the buttons and release their finger, triggering the button tap.

I have complete control over my buttons, touchables, and views (even the tab bar is custom, as opposed to the illustrations I made above).

How can I achieve this? (I'm on React Native 0.63)

Comment: I don't think it could work because the other touch will not work until you release the current long pressed area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better solution to this but off the top of my head I would use the Gesture Responder System

https://reactnative.dev/docs/gesture-responder-system

You can have a one container view that wraps tab bar and buttons. Then listen to the `onResponderMove` event to decide when these buttons should appear. This may happen for example when the `locationY` exceeds some value.

You can also use the `onResponderRelease` event (again with the help of `locationX`  and `locationY` parameters) to determine if the finger was released above the button.

Comment: I went with a very similar approach. Basically, I made a `GestureButton` component where I basically replicated press in/out/long press events from a view's responder to act as a regular button. Then I made a `GestureTarget` class which, when mounted and on layout, registers itself into a static array with the layout rect of the wrapped view in screen. Then on the `GestureButton` class, i check for hit rect for any objects within that array on responder move. There might be better approaches, for sure, but it works flawlessly for my case. (and yes I do remove them from the array on unmount :))

Comment: Similar situation, answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76374112/999032. Demo: https://snack.expo.dev/@canxerian/component-touched-during-touch-move-event