# React Native detect if component was touched during a drag event

Tags: react-native

I have a grid of Views and would like for each View to be notified when if one is touched during a drag event.

How can I implement something like this in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

The idea:

1. Maintain a list of references to the items
2. Apply a [`PanResponder`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder) on the parent View
3. Inside `onPanResponderMove` call [`measure`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation#measurecallback) and perform a point inside bounding box calculation - if true, then touch inside element detected.

Note: `useMemo` is used instead of `useRef` for the `PanResponder` implementation, as the former enables us to use the state object, `hoveredIndexes` as a dependency. Otherwise we'd get stale

Demo:
https://snack.expo.dev/@canxerian/component-touched-during-touch-move-event

Comment: Wish I'd seen this before doing something very similar. nice solution!